# What is the $x$ in $\log_b x$ called?

Tags: terminology, logarithms

In $b^a = x$, $b$ is the base, a is the exponent and $x$ is the result of the operation. But in its logarithm counterpart, $\log_{b}(x) = a$, $b$ is still the base, and $a$ is now the result. What is $x$ called here? The exponent?

Comment: In $b^a=x$, $x$ (or the whole of $b^a$) is sometimes called the *power*.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Argument (as you call the $x$ in any $f(x)$ argument of the function)

Answer (score 20):

Another name (that I've only ever seen when someone else asked this [question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Archives/Mathematics/2010_February_17#Follow_up:_the_name_for_the_argument_of_the_logarithmic_function)) is "logarithmand".

---

From [page 36](http://books.google.com/books?id=9uoDAAAAQAAJ&vq=logarithmand&pg=PA36) of *[The Spirit of Mathematical Analysis](http://books.google.com/books?id=9uoDAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover)* by [Martin Ohm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Ohm), translated from the German by [Alexander John Ellis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_John_Ellis), 1843:

[image: page from The Spirit of Mathematical Analysis]

Comment: Would you mind if I added to your answer an image of the text where "logarithmand" is introduced in the book mentioned in your link?

Comment: @Jonas Meyer: Please feel free to add the image; that would be neat to see.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

antilogarithm (noun): a compound of Greek anti-"against" and logarithm (qq. v.). In algebra if $log_{b}(x) = y$, y is the logarithm of x, and x is said to be the antilogarithm of y.

Source: The Words of Mathematics: An Etymological Dictionary of Mathematical Terms Used in English, Steven Schwartzman

Comment: I often see things like $\mathrm{antilog}_b\;y$ in engineering and chemistry books, which annoys me a lot because people could have just as easily written $10^y$ or $e^y$

Comment: @J.M.: True. Much like the weird "conventions" on inverse functions at all. _asin_, _arc_, _anti_, $\bar{f}$, ... If at all, I'd write $log^-1$

Comment: @Dario: I don't even care for the superscript -1 myself. I only use it when showing something to other people but with some gritting of teeth. For personal notes, I use D.J. Jeffrey's hacek notation.

Comment: @Bill: To be upfront, I suppose for me the issue is more aesthetic/psychological than mathematical. I think I'd flip when I see $\exp$ with a subscript. ;)

Comment: @J.M.: The point is uniformity. I'd much rather see $\rm \log_b\ exp_b\ x = x\ $ than $\rm\ \log_b\ antilog_b\ x$.