# How do I prove $\log(x^n)=n\log|x|$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

By definition we know that: $\log(x^n)=n\log|x|$ as known property in logarithm function .

If it's not a trivial question, how do I prove that :$\log(x^n)=n\log|x|$?

Note: $x$ is real number, $n$ is a natural number.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the $x$ in $\log_b x$ called?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4214/what-is-the-x-in-log-b-x-called)

Comment: What is your definition for the logarithm? (depending on the way it was defined to you, the answer may change)

Comment: ok, I meant logarithm neip

Comment: No, I mean: "how was the logarithm defined" (as the reciprocal of the exponential, as the only solution of a specific differential equation, or something else? All these definitions are equivalent, but depending on which one you start, proving some properties of the logarithm can be more or less difficult.

Comment: Ah, ok receprocal of the exponential

Comment: without explanation, you saw the formula how it was written , then you can immediatly deduce whicvh logarithm ?

Comment: i want for exemple : not prove property in logarithm by other unproved property but example :using series ,..integral

Comment: @zeraouliarafik The 'other unproved property' can be used as a definition ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) and [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Logarithm.html) use $\log_b x=k\Leftrightarrow b^k=x$ as a definition), as shown in my answer.

Comment: @zeraouliarafik You said you define it this way too (by 'reciprocal of the exponential' you mean the same).

Comment: First you must note that $x$ should be positive and hence no need for absolute value here. The property can be proved if we use the most fundamental property of $\log$ namely $\log (ab) = \log a + \log b$. From this we easily get $$\log (x_{1}x_{2}\cdots x_{n}) = \log x_{1} + \log x_{2} + \cdots + \log x_{n}$$ Putting $x_{1} = x_{2} = \cdots = x_{n} = x$ we get $\log x^{n} = n\log x$.

Answer (score 3):

It is only true when $x^n> 0$, so we assume it.

We'll use the following definition, which is how [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) and [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Logarithm.html) define it: $$\log_b x=k\iff b^k=x$$

together with the exponentiation rule: $\,\displaystyle{b^{xy}=\left(b^y\right)^x}$

$$\log_b(x^n)=n\log_b |x|\iff b^{n\log_b |x|}=x^n$$

$$\iff \left(b^{\log_b |x|}\right)^n=x^n\iff |x|^n=x^n$$

$$\iff |x^n|=x^n,$$

which is true.

Comment: it's a trivial answer

Comment: you proved a problem by problem

Comment: @zeraouliarafik The following definition of $\log_b x$ was used here: $\log_b x=k\iff b^k=x$. That was all that was used, together with exponentiation rules.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $log(x) : (0,\infty ) \to (-\infty,\infty )$

Defined by $x=e^{log(x)}$

Consider $n \in \mathbb{N}$

$x^n=e^y$

$\iff log(x^n)=y$

$\iff x^n=e^y$

$\iff x=e^{y/n}$

$\iff log(x)=y/n$

$\iff nlog(x)=y$

Comment: what about if x=0 in your answer ?

Comment: log(0) is undefined

Comment: Then your answer is undefined

Comment: I've edited my solution so I am clear about the domains and ranges of the functions.

Comment: I think you mean $log:(0,\infty)\rightarrow(-\infty,\infty)$. The logarithm definitely takes negative values.

Comment: if x=1/2 then logx is negative not in (0,infty) as you defined your function

Comment: This answer seems correct only if you assume earlier that $x \neq 0$ and in the fourth step you need have $|x| = e^{y/n}$

Comment: log(0) is not defined so it is wrong to talk about log(0)

Comment: e^(logx) always positive for x>0 and  not in (-infty,+infty)

Answer (score 0):

There are already correct answers above/below, but for clarity sake, I try to put another (a more clear?) version:
Let $x \neq 0$ and suppose $y = \log (x^n)$ (here unless we are in complex domain, $x^n >0$). Then by  definition $ e^y = x^n$. Since $e^y$ is positive
$$
|x| = e^{y/n}
$$
(this is analytically true).
Taking back $\log$ we get
$$
n \log(|x|) = y
$$

Thus you have proved a formula:

**Prop**
For $x \in \mathbb{R} , n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x^n >0$, 
$$
n \log(|x|) = \log(x^n).
$$

Comment: let x=-1 , what about =log(x^n)  if n is odd natural number  ?

Comment: In that case $n$ must be even

Comment: but in my question we are in real numbers !!!!!

Comment: @zeraouliarafik Then the statement that you're trying to prove is **false**.

Comment: Yes he is right

Comment: no, only to use mathematical logic , i'm not claim to be false

Comment: The above formula does not hold for arbitrary real $x$ and natural $n$; in this case $\log$ is not even defined properly

Comment: but it is famous and known at all

Comment: If you consider in real numbers only, the domain of $\log$ should be restricted to $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: @zeraouliarafik perhaps you can find a reference, then.  Or, perhaps you simply meant to write
$$
\log\left| x^n\right| = n \log |x|
$$

Comment: @zeraouliarafik if you could find a text or webpage that states agrees that the statement you're trying to prove is *true*, I would be very interested in taking a look.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, you know what's a famous property in logarithm, it's always used by students, mathematicians , researchers, i'm also as you am seeking to know a proof that show that's correct

Comment: @zeraouliarafik if it's "always used", as you claim that it is, then surely you could find **one** example of its use in a paper or textbook.

Comment: If you want to prove the above formula for all real $x \neq 0 $ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (though I'm not sure it'd be true), you need to extend your consideration to complex numbers, extending the domain of $\log$ to complex numbers